# Stadford-nlp and ParallelGC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, stanford-nlp

I'm using StanfordNLP. The typical code is like this:

```
public class SegmentParser {
    private CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier;

    @Autowired
    public SegmentParser(String path) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("sighanCorporaDict", path);
        props.setProperty("NormalizationTable", path + "/norm.simp.utf8");
        props.setProperty("normTableEncoding", "UTF-8");
        props.setProperty("serDictionary", path + "/dict-chris6.ser.gz");
        props.setProperty("inputEncoding", "UTF-8");
        props.setProperty("sighanPostProcessing", "true");
        classifier = new CRFClassifier<CoreLabel>(props);
        classifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(path + "/ctb.gz", props);
    }

    public List<String> parse(String sentence) {
        return classifier.segmentString(sentence);
    }
}

public class NLParser {
    private  LexicalizedParser lp;

    @Autowired
    private SegmentParser sParser;

    @Autowired
    public NLParser(String path) {
        String[] options = { "-maxLength", "140", "-MAX_ITEMS","5000000"};
        lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(path, options);
    }


    public String getMust(String sentence) {
        List<String> words = sParser.parse(sentence);
        List<CoreLabel> labels = Sentence.toCoreLabelList((String[]) words.toArray());
        Tree tree = lp.apply(labels);
        List<TypedDependency> tdl = new ChineseTreebankLanguagePack().grammaticalStructureFactory().newGrammaticalStructure(tree).typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
        // changed must to set, order by hashCode()
        TreeSet<IndexedWord> mustCandidate = new TreeSet<IndexedWord>(new IndexedWordComparator());
        for (TypedDependency td: tdl) {
            if (td.reln().getShortName().equals("dobj")) {
                mustCandidate.add(td.dep());
            } else if (td.reln().getShortName().equals("nn")) {
                mustCandidate.add(td.gov());
            }
        }

        if (mustCandidate.isEmpty()) {
            return new String("");
        }
        return mustCandidate.pollLast().value();
    }
}
```

I created 1 NLParser object and share it among 8 threads. The performance is about 9 sentences per seconds at the begining. and later, seems it hangs on Parallel GC.

Here is the result of jstack

```
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f925280e800 nid=0x2503 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f925280f800 nid=0x2703 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9252810000 nid=0x2903 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9252810800 nid=0x2b03 runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9252811000 nid=0x2d03 runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9252812000 nid=0x2f03 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9252812800 nid=0x3103 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9252813000 nid=0x3303 runnable
```

The command I used is

```
java -Xms4g -Xmx8g -DnThreads=8 -Dfull=y -jar target/nlp.jar

LM-SHC-00950567:learn01 zhifan$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_40"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

My question is is there any way I can prevent so many ParallelGc and tunning the NLP performance?

Comment: you should enable GC logging with `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails`, that should provide further insight. Your use of a treeset seems wasteful though if all you want to do is to find the largest element.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!  the treeset is wasteful, I have removed it.  I just change the GC collection to G1, it works perfectly.   As for the stadford-nlp performance, I changed parse module from xinhuaFactored to xinhuaPCFG, the speed increased by 20 ~ 30x.